# Erro: In Ops.factor

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com um data.frame de dados climáticos e quero saber se os dados estão dentro dos limites de leitura dos equipamento. Para isso os limites de tolerância adotados para temperatura (`temp_med`, `temp_max` e `temp_min`) são de -40 ° C a + 60 ° C. Em uma nova coluna é atribuida as notas: `1` quando os dados estiverem dentro desse limite, `3` para quando estiver fora e `7` quando a linha não  possuir dados.

Script usado:

```
lim_temp<- (-40)<= dados_horas$temp_med & dados_horas$temp_med <= 60
dados_horas$nota1_temp_med [lim_temp] <- 5L
dados_horas$nota1_temp_med [!lim_temp] <- 6L
dados_horas$nota1_temp_med <- 7L
```

obs: `dados_horas` - Nome do meu banco de dados; `temp_med` - coluna que quero trabalhar; `nota1_temp_med` - nova coluna com as notas.

Mas está aparecendo aparecendo o seguinte erro:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In Ops.factor(dados_horas$temp_med, (-40)) :
>     ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
>   2: In Ops.factor(dados_horas$temp_med, 60) :
>     ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors

O que devo fazer para corrigir esse erro?

Parte do banco de dados:

```
dia data    hora    temp_med    temp_max    temp_min
1   01/01/2012  12:00:20 AM 20.345  20.517  20.145
1   01/01/2012  1:00:07 AM  20.242  20.523  20.021
1   01/01/2012  2:00:08 AM  19.916  20.071  19.462
1   01/01/2012  3:00:08 AM  19.332  19.452  19.26
1   01/01/2012  4:00:08 AM  19.1    19.449  18.528
1   01/01/2012  5:00:08 AM  18.434  18.526  18.398
1   01/01/2012  6:00:08 AM  18.411  18.443  18.379
1   01/01/2012  7:00:08 AM  18.663  19.087  18.396
1   01/01/2012  8:00:07 AM  19.576  20.089  19.097
1   01/01/2012  9:00:07 AM  20.613  21.393  20.06
1   01/01/2012  10:00:07 AM 22.22   23.83   21.4
1   01/01/2012  11:00:07 AM 23.412  23.875  22.842
1   01/01/2012  12:00:08 PM 23.87   24.774  23.222
1   01/01/2012  1:00:08 PM  22.195  24.474  20.645
1   01/01/2012  2:00:08 PM  23.03   23.579  22.674
1   01/01/2012  3:00:08 PM  24.016  24.845  22.82
1   01/01/2012  4:00:08 PM  24.095  25.074  23.343
1   01/01/2012  5:00:08 PM  23.831  25.064  23.193
1   01/01/2012  6:00:08 PM  22.71   23.203  21.944
1   01/01/2012  7:00:07 PM  22.036  22.629  21.277
1   01/01/2012  8:00:07 PM  20.959  21.32   20.503
1   01/01/2012  9:00:07 PM  20.208  20.659  19.583
1   01/01/2012  10:00:07 PM 19.743  20.029  19.381
1   01/01/2012  11:00:07 PM 19.98   20.224  19.709
2   02/01/2012  12:00:20 AM 20.032  20.149  19.872
```

Comment: Esse erro significa que `temp_med` está a ser lido como `factor` Faça `dados_horas$temp_med <- as.numeric(as.character(dados_horas$temp_med))`.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme apontado nos comentários pelo @RuiBarradas, a mensagem de erro está informando que esta operação não é significativa para fatores.

No [r](/questions/tagged/r), fatores são variáveis categóricas. E de fato não há razões para acreditar que possam haver comparações do tipo maior ou menor entre variáveis como "Homem"/"Mulher" ou "Ásia"/"América"/"África".

Este problema ocorreu porque dados numéricos foram lidos como **fator**. Para resolver-lo, basta transformar os dados para numéricos.

Na solução proposta pelo @RuiBarradas nos comentários,

```
dados_horas$temp_med <- as.numeric(as.character(dados_horas$temp_med))
```

Vale lembrar que para transformar dados de fator para numéricos é preciso, antes transformá-lo em texto.